# How to pass data to BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment class. Looks like this:

```
public class BottomSheetAddProp extends BottomSheetDialogFragment
```

It has a method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView
```

In this method I create a RecyclerView with RecycleAdapter for photos.

```
        recyclerPhotos = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerPhotos);
        recyclerPhotos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManagerPhotos = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerAdapterPhotos = new AdapterPhotos(selectedPhotos, getActivity());
        recyclerPhotos.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerPhotos);
        recyclerPhotos.setAdapter(recyclerAdapterPhotos);
```

The data about chosen photos comes to `onActivityResult` method and I have to performe a `recyclerAdapterPhotos.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the RecyclerView List. But in Activity I don't have this `recyclerAdapterPhotos` because it was created inside BottomSheetAddProp.

My question is - how to make `.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onActivityResult()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method in your dialog fragment:

```
public void updatedData(Data data) {
    adapter.setData(data);
}
```

Hold the reference to your fragment inside activity. Then in onActivityResult method just pass the data through the method above:

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Data data = ...
    dialogFragment.updateDate(data);
}
```

Comment: Your answer gives me an idea. I created a method in my activity which gets Adapter from my Fragment. Thanks!